# Auto-Fit HTML Content with Only CSS or Java

Tags: html, playstation3

i'm making several web pages for PlayStation 3 system, it only supports html, some css and javascript

I don't know any of those coding but i managed to get a html done

This is a page i made

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>PlayStation® Radio</title>
   </head>
   <script>
      javascript:window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height)
   </script>
   <body onload="changeScreenSize()">
      <style>
         body { background-image:url("http://raw.githubusercontent.com/LuanTeles/PS3-4K-Pro/main/Web_Pages/media/radio.png");
         background-size: 100% auto; 
         background-attachment: scroll;
         margin-top: 3%; 
         margin-left: 8%; 
         margin-right: 8%; 
         marginbottom: 8%;}
         body {background-color:#000000;}
         body {color:white;}
         }
      </style>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/LuanTeles/PS3-4K-Pro/raw/main/Web_Pages/script/flash_objects.js"></script>
      <div id="player_936" align="center">
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars_936 = {};
            var params_936 = {
                quality: "low",
                wmode: "transparent",
                bgcolor: "#ffffff",
                allowScriptAccess: "always",
                allowFullScreen: "true",
                flashvars: "fichier=http://github.com/LuanTeles/ScreenSavers/releases/download/Winamp/Winamp_Visualization.mp4&auto_play=true&apercu=http://raw.githubusercontent.com/LuanTeles/PS3-4K-Pro/main/Web_Pages/media/visualizer_preview.png"
            };
            var attributes_936 = {};
            flashObject("http://github.com/LuanTeles/PS3-4K-Pro/raw/main/Web_Pages/swf/video_player/video_player_28.swf", "player_936", "1080", "660", "8", false, flashvars_936, params_936, attributes_936);
         </script>
      </div>
      <div id="player_9428" align="center">
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars_9428 = {};
            var params_9428 = {
                quality: "low",
                wmode: "transparent",
                bgcolor: "#ffffff",
                allowScriptAccess: "always",
                allowFullScreen: "true",
                flashvars: "url=http://relay.181.fm:8128&autostart=yes"
            };
            var attributes_9428 = {};
            flashObject("http://github.com/LuanTeles/PS3-4K-Pro/raw/main/Web_Pages/swf/music_player/music_player_6.swf", "player_9428", "1080", "35", "8", false, flashvars_9428, params_9428, attributes_9428);
         </script>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

It looks great on 1080p resolution

[1080p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67cH3.jpg)

But in 720 as example it looks terrible

[720p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhMnB.jpg)

How can i make it fit different resolutions?

Comment: Do you mean **JavaScript** or **Java**? They're not the same thing

Comment: Javascript, sorry